# 'max.message.bytes' exception when connecting Control Center to Confluent Cloud Kafka

Tags: confluent-cloud, confluent-control-center

I'm setting up a Dockerized Confluent Control Center which points to our Confluent Cloud Kafka and I've hit this *common* issue [HERE](https://docs.confluent.io/current/control-center/installation/troubleshooting.html) and [HERE](https://github.com/confluentinc/ccloud-tools/issues/5):

```
[2019-07-31 20:40:28,023] ERROR [main] attempt=failed to create topic=TopicInfo{name=_confluent-metrics, partitions=12, replication=3} (io.confluent.controlcenter.KafkaHelper)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.PolicyViolationException: Config property 'max.message.bytes' with value '10485760' exceeded max limit of 8388608.
```

According to those references, the solution is to set a property:

```
confluent.metrics.topic.max.message.bytes=8388608
```

Unfortunately, I can't find the proper env to make the magic happen after several variations. Here is *every* variation I've tried in my docker-compose.yml:

```
      CONTROL_CENTER_OPTS: "-Dconfluent.metrics.topic.max.message.bytes=8388608"
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_MAX_MESSAGE_BYTES: 8388608
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_MAX_MESSAGE_BYTES: 8388608
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE: 8388608
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_MAX_MESSAGE_BYTES: 8388608
      MAX_MESSAGE_BYTES: 8388608
```

Has anyone been successful getting a C3 container connected to Confluent Cloud? or, more specifically, passed this roadblock?

The end goal is to have a UI for visibility over a dockerized KSqlDB/cli running locally, but connected to Confluent Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Found the one version I didn't try:

```js
      CONTROL_CENTER_METRICS_TOPIC_MAX_MESSAGE_BYTES: 8388608
```